# Area of curves and intersection

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, area, polygons

The area of a closed polygonal plane curve can be defined using the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula). Let $A_1$,..., $A_n$ be the vertices of the curve and $O$ be some origin in the plane. Set $A_{n+1} = A_1$.

$$
\mbox{area}(A_1,..., A_n) = {1 \over 2}\sum_{i=1}^n \det(\overrightarrow{OA_i}, \overrightarrow{OA_{i+1}})
$$

I am looking for an elementary (algebraic) proof that a polygon has a non-zero area. Equivalently, for a proof that a polygonal curve with zero area has a self-intersection.

By elementary, I mean I don't want to rely on the existence of triangulations for polygons nor on the Jordan separation theorem since I would like to use the shoelace formula to prove these results.

Answer (score 1):

Use Gauss or Greens's theorems to locate a point of self intersection for zero net area.

Comment: I don't understand. The Green's formula is the shoelace formula for polygon. So yes, I want to use it, this is my question.